# How to show an ajax like on particular post using post id

Tags: javascript

I am displaying ajax likes on number of posts but the problem is that when i click 'like button' the likes (without loading the page) display on first post only and when i refresh the page all the likes display on their own places.
I want to show ajax like on the particular post not on only the first one. I guess i need to pass the ID in success function but i do not know how. Here is the code. 
In my code: a Rumor is a post, Like  = approve, dislike = disapprove.

View Ajax + That Particular part of Html View

```js
function approve_rumor(r_id) {
  // alert("dfdfdf");
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('Home1/approve_rumor') ?>",
    data: {
      r_id: r_id
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(val) {
      if (true) {
        $('#showapp').html(val);
      } else {
        // <?php //echo base_url('Login'); ?>;
        alert("You need to Login");
      }
    }

  });
}
```

```html
<span class="like-listing fll approve" onclick="approve_rumor(<?php echo $rumors->rumor_id; ?>)">
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
<span id="showapp" class="fll"><?php echo $rumors->rumor_totalapprovals ?></span>
```

Controller

```php
function approve_rumor() {

  if ($this - > session - > userdata('user_email', 'user_id')) {
    $this - > load - > model('rumor_model');
    $r_id = $this - > input - > post('r_id');
    $data['user_id'] = $this - > session - > userdata('user_id');
    $data['rumor_id'] = $r_id;
    $this - > rumor_model - > ApproveRumor($data);

    //$this->load->view('home1',['approval'=>$approval]);
  } else {
    return redirect('Login');
  }
}
```

```php
function ApproveRumor($data) {
  // echo "<pre>";
  // print_r($data);
  // exit;
  $r_id = $data['rumor_id'];
  $query = $this - > db - > insert('approval', $data);
  if ($query) {
    $a = $this - > db - > query("SELECT * ,  count(rumor_id) as count_like FROM approval WHERE rumor_id = $r_id ");
    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($a - > row() - > count_like);

    $totalapprovals = $a - > row() - > count_like;
    $this - > db - > query("UPDATE rumors SET rumor_totalapprovals = $totalapprovals WHERE rumor_id = $r_id");
    // echo $totalapprovals; 
    //  $this->db->where('rumors.rumor_id',$r_id);
    //  $res = $this->db->update('rumors',$totalapprovals);

  } else {
    echo "0";
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(true) {} else {}` mean that the `else` branch is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

A cool way I've found to pass data through to the $.ajax callback function is adding a custom option and then referencing it in the $.ajax callback as this.optionProp:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "your/url/here",
    data: {
      r_id: r_id
    },
    r_id:r_id,  //Your custom option
    cache: false,
    success: function(val) {
      console.log("r_id: " + this.r_id);  //The custom option can be referenced with this.optProp
    }

  });
```

Let me know if this helps or is not what you are looking for and we'll get it fixed

Comment: Thank You, can you please explain this process.

Comment: How to pass link the id with the view here         "$('#showapp').html(val);"

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an object from your server side function that has an `id` attribute so you can call it after success like this:

```
   function approve_rumor(r_id) {
   // alert("dfdfdf");
   $.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url: "<?php echo base_url('Home1/approve_rumor') ?>",
   data: {
   r_id: r_id
   },
 cache: false,
 success: function(val) {
 var id = val.id; //gets the id attribute from the returned val Object
 }
});
}
```

Comment: How to pass link the id with the view here "$('#showapp').html(val);"